# jQuery Selection by Title query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to display the contents of `data-title` of the `div` . I want to select the `div` by using the `title` of the `div`.

**jQuery Snippet**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[title^=\"Shirt\"]").click(function () {
        alert($("div[title^=\"Shirt\"]").attr("data-title"));
    });
});
```

**HTML Snippet**

```
<div title="Shirt Front" data-title="SF">Click to get Shirt Front</div>
<div title="Shirt Back" data-title="SB">Click to get Shirt Back</div>
```

When I click on the div with title "Shirt Front" I get SF.
When I click on the div with title "Shirt Back" I get SF instead of SB.

Here is the JSFiddle demonstrating it. http://jsfiddle.net/Q6nBZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [.data() API](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for this.

alert($(this).data('title'));

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$(this)` to target current clicked div:

```
alert($(this).attr("data-title"));
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6nBZ/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($(this).attr("data-title"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6nBZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).data('title');
```

[jQuery.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) documentation

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div[title^=\"Shirt\"]").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("data-title"));
  });
});
```